# HTC Dream keeps on showing power options screen

Tags: htc-dream, power-options

I have an HTC Dream cell phone which was working fine till last night. Today morning I woke up to find that the cell phone battery had completely discharged. So, I replaced the battery with an extra one.

I powered on the cell phone and I am surprised to find the "power options" screen turn up every few seconds. Pressing any button also makes the "power options" screen turn up. I tried resetting the cell phone to factory settings. I even tried a hard reset but still this problem persists. Any idea how I could solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a stock ROM, I suggest you root the phone (the warranty's way gone) and upgrade it to CyanogenMod 4 (Android 1.6) or CyanogenMod 6 (Android 2.2).

Battery life is very good on 4; 6 is more recent version of Android -- however there are some additional hoops to jump through to get it installed.

The first step in most Dream rooting instructions is to downgrade it to a vulnerable version, so you will lose data stored on the phone. You might have luck with one of the "one-click root" programs but if you can't kill the "Power Options" dialog every few seconds, you may just need to flash it with the RC29 DREAIMG.NBH.

Comment: My problem got solved on its own. I dont know how but now its working fine. Still I would love to upgrade it to 1.6 or 2.2 I heard that Android 2.2 doesnt work well with the Dream phone. Its quite slow. So, I was hoping that it works well with 1.6. If you have any link which mentions the upgradation process in detail, please do let me know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: 2.2 needs some configuration but it's usable. You have to turn off a lot of fancy stuff.

Answer (score -3):

Disabling fast boot may resolv the problem as it did for my brotrher

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? I am new to Android and dont know much about it.

Comment: just google it its that easy

Comment: I googled to find the following post: http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fastboot. Here it mentions that the G1 phones have the fastboot disabled by default. So, what do I do? Do you think flashing it with a new android OS will help?

Comment: "fastboot" isn't the problem here. "fastboot" refers the bootloader.